# Show that $f(z) = |z|$ is not differentiable anywhere.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, complex-numbers, absolute-value

Show that $f(z) = |z|$ is not differentiable anywhere.

I already know that $f(z) = |z|^2$ is differentiable at $0$, but I am unsure how to show that $f(z) = |z|$ is not. I have set up the definition of a derivative below, but I do not know how to approach solving this, particularly the part $|z+\lambda|$, since I know for complex numbers $|z| = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$.

$\lim _{\lambda\to \:0}\left(\frac{\left|z+\lambda\right|-\left|z\right|}{\lambda}\right)$

Comment: Are you sure about $|z|^2$?

Comment: My apologies, I know that $|z|^2$ is not differentiable everywhere.

Comment: write that as $\epsilon \to 0$  : $|z_0+\epsilon| = |z_0| + \epsilon C+ o(\epsilon)$ for some $C \ne 0$, and you get that the RHS isn't real, a contradiction

Comment: My first instinct would be to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations... if I don't see a better answer soon, I'll give that an earnest try myself.

Comment: ...and it suddenly hits me that it's laughably easy.  Since the imaginary part is identically zero, its derivative is identically zero, so it will never be equal to both the derivative of the real part with respect to x and the negation of the same with respect to y.

Comment: $f$ isn't real differentiable at $z=0$, let alone complex.

Comment: Note that if $|z|$ is differentiable then so is $|z|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

So you'll want to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations, that for $x + iy = f(a+bi)$, $x,y,a,b$ all real, $f(z)$ is differentiable iff:

$$\frac{\delta x}{\delta a} = \frac{\delta y}{\delta b}$$
$$\frac{\delta y}{\delta a} = -\frac{\delta x}{\delta b}$$

In this case, $\delta y/\delta a$ and $\delta y/\delta b$ are both identically zero, since the absolute value has no imaginary part.  The partials of the real part, which is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, are $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ respectively.  The equations are only satisfied when these are both zero, but since each is zero only if $a$ or $b$ is zero, and neither exists if both are zero, the equations are never satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Take $z_0\in\Bbb C$. If $z_0=0$, then $f$ is not differentiable at $z_0$ because the limit$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{|z|}z$$doesn't exist (if $z\in(0,\infty)$, then $\frac{|z|}z=1$ and if $z\in(-\infty,0)$, then $\frac{|z|}z=-1$). And if $z_0\ne0$, if $f$ was differentiable at $z_0$, then $f^2$ would also be differentiable at $z_0$. But you already know that $f^2$ is not differentiable at $z_0$ when $z_0\ne0$.